# IBM Worklight - Page fragmentation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to migrate existing phonegap project into worklight. Phonegap app is using  $.mobile.changePage() for page navigation. Will this function reload the existing DOM or creates a new DOM. As worklight suggest to use single DOM object, if I use $.mobile.changePage() will it have any impact on worklight application behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) training module: [Building a multi-page app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf) ([sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip)).

---

**jQuery.mobile.changePage()**
http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

**.load()**
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Please read the above documentation to understand the difference between `changePage` and `load`.

Comment: I have gone through the IBM Worklight training modules and I am quite clear about the page fragmentation concept. But I am really confused to figure out the difference between the functionality provided by  $.mobile.changePage() and worklight's $('selector').load(); Sir, Could you please explain me in detail.

Comment: 1) $('selector').load() is not Worklight's - it is jQuery's. 2) they are not the same at all. 3) See my updated answer.